# ERROR LNK1276 invalid 'DLL' directive in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c, dll, visual-studio-2005, linker-errors

I'm trying to build a DLL in C language using Visual Studio 2005 but i get the error:

> Error LNK1276 : invalid 'DLL' directive : does not start with '/'

Building in debug mode succeeds , the error comes out when building in release mode. I've seen the MSDN documentation, it says that is caused by #pragma instructions but i don't have any of this instructions. 
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks

EDIT : Hi , thanks for your replies. I tried to use the option 'Generate Preprocessed File' under 'Property Pages' -> 'C/C++' -> 'Preprocessor' in order to generate a .i file. Then i searched in that file #pragma comment instructions , i found two lines like this:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"uuid.lib")
```

located in the header file ServProv.h (under Visual Studio 8 directory). Could this be the problem ?

Comment: Are you sure that none of your files (incl. any non-Visual-Studio-headers) include `#pragma` or `__pragma`?

Comment: `/DLL` is indeed a linker option.  And it indeed appears to be injected with #pragma comment, missing the `/`.  You'll have to find it.